# vs2013 professional and vs2013 community in the same computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible?

Actually i use vs2013 professional for the work and i can to install vs2013 community in the same computer for my personal commercial use.

Thanks

Comment: I would actually keep my work in a Virtual Machine or something for various legal and privacy reasons. No idea if you can run multiple editions of the same VS release on a single system though.

Comment: If your employer forbids you from using your work machine for personal projects then do consider that installing another VS version does not in any way alters the intent of such a rule.  Talk to your supervisor first.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. In fact if you uninstall professional and install community it will pick up your old professional license from the registry.